# Ejecutar "Buscar todas las referencias" de una función durante ejecución C#

Tags: c#

He estado desarrollando una aplicación Windows Forms de Visual Studio 2019 en C#, la aplicación es considerablemente grande con varios formularios, recientemente se me solicitó traducir la aplicación y por lo tanto desarrollé una clase llamada duv_Class_funciones y en esa clase tengo una función:

```
public string traducir(Form formulario, string clave, Boolean inversa = false)
```

en todos los forms tengo algunos mensajes emergentes en español que dice cosas como "El Usuario ya existe.", entonces remplazé los mensajes con:

```
(new duv_Class_funciones()).traducir(this, "El Usuario ya existe.")
```

Funciona correctamente, remplaza el texto con su respectiva traducción pero estos mensajes pueden aumentar conforme esté actualizando la aplicación y necesito agregar la correspondiente traducción a la base de datos y por ahora son mas de 400 traducciones.
para traducir los objetos tales como botones y otros controles hice la siguiente rutina:

```
public List<Control[]> lista_de_controles_en_todos_los_forms_de_tipo(string tipo)
    {
        List<Control[]> controles = new List<Control[]>();
        List<Form> formularios = lista_de_forms();
        foreach (Form formulario in formularios)
        {
            if(tipo.ToLower() == "form")
            {
                Control[] form = { formulario, formulario };
                controles.Add(form);
            }
            else
            {
                List<Control> controles_de_formulario = lista_de_controles_de_tipo(formulario, tipo);
                foreach (Control control in controles_de_formulario)
                {
                    Control[] form_control = { formulario, control };
                    controles.Add(form_control);
                }
            }
        }
        return controles;
    }
```

La rutina busca todos los controles en todos los forms de tipo "tipo" y me regresa una lista que contiene Control[], de tal forma que el primer índice me regresa el form de origen y el segundo elemento me regresa el control de tal forma que me regresa una lista con 1014 controles con sus respectivos formularios de origen.

**Todo lo anterior es para dar contexto.**

La cosa es que quiero hacer una función que tenga la estructura

```
public List<string[]> strings_a_traducir()
    {
        List<string[]> lista_form_string = new List<string[]>();
        foreach(Form formulario in lista_de_forms())
        {
            foreach(var referencia in Buscar_todas_las_referencias("traducir"))
            {
                string[] form_string = new string[2];
                form_string[0] = formulario.Name;
                form_string[1] = referencia.segundo_campo;//si una referencia es (new duv_Class_funciones()).traducir(this, "El Usuario ya existe.") entonces segundo_campo="El Usuario ya existe."
                lista_form_string.Add(form_string);
            }
        }
        return lista_form_string;
    }
```

Entonces la pregunta es ¿Cómo hacer la función Buscar_todas_las_referencias(string funcion)?

¿Alguien tiene alguna sugerencia?

Me serviría si la función me regresa una lista de strings que contengan por ejemplo el valor "duv_Class_funciones()).traducir(this, "El Usuario ya existe.")"

Doy gracias de antemano a todos los que respondan

Nota: se que se puede dar clic derecho en la función "traducir" y oprimir la opción "Buscar todas las referencias" y aparece básicamente la lista que quiero pero necesito que se ejecute durante la ejecución del código para poder guardarla automáticamente en la base de datos